# Dict within a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the following data structure and written code:

```
alpha = {'Jan': [1,2,3]}
beta = {'Jan': [4,5,6]}
carter = {'Jan': ['boo', 'fee', 'lee']}

delta = {month: {month: [b-a for (b, a) in zip(be, al)]
                for (month, be), (month, al) in zip(beta.items(), alpha.items())}
        for month, ca in carter.items()}

print(delta)
{'Jan': {'Jan': [3, 3, 3]}}
```

However, I want the result to look like this:

```
{'Jan': {'boo': 3, 'fee': 3, 'lee': 3}
```

what is the right way to write this to get desired result?

Comment: Can you explain the logic here? Specifically, why are all the values 3?

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the variable `month` to mean multiple different things simultaneously.

Comment: @ArthurKing, logic is subtract elements in list values a from list values b

Comment: @DeepSpace. I have edited this. sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you meant your output as `{'Jan': {'boo': 3, 'fee': 3, 'lee': 3}}`:

```
delta = {month: 
            {ca : (b - a) for ca, b, a in zip(carter[month], beta[month], alpha[month])} 
            for month in carter.keys()}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple dictionary comprehension should help:

```
alpha = {'Jan': [1,2,3]}
beta = {'Jan': [4,5,6]}
carter = {'Jan': ['boo', 'fee', 'lee']}
K = list(alpha)[0]
delta = {K: {n: a - b for n, a, b in zip(Carter[K], beta[K], alpha[K])}}
print(delta)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Jan': {'boo': 3, 'fee': 3, 'lee': 3}}
```

Comment: This works only for a single month.

Comment: @matszwecja How many other months do you see in the sample data?

Comment: You can clearly see in the original comprehension that OP expects multiple key/value pairs in the carter dictionary.

Comment: The code is just a sample code. The main data contains 12 months, with multiple key/value pairs in each of the variables